# How to replace an element of a string at a given index

Tags: f#

```
string s = "foo.bar"
s[s.LastIndexOf(".")] = "-"
```

It sounds dead simple in c-like languages, but drives me nuts in F#

my code:

```
let sb = new StringBuilder(s)
sb.[s.LastIndexOf(".")] <- '-'
let s = sb.ToString()
```

Is there more elegant way to do this? Like using `|>` ? I don't want to explicitly declare a new variable `sb`.

Comment: You could wrap that into a function, but there's no way (at least in F#, as there's no `unsafe`) of manipulating a `string` directly. `string`s are immutable in .NET

Comment: how about: `s.Substring(0, index) + "-" + s.Substring(index + 1)` to avoid mutation

Comment: And how about `s.[..i-1]+string c+s.[i+1..]`, using F#'s own string slices?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can do this as follows:

```
let s = "foo.bar"
let index = s.LastIndexOf('.')
let s1 = s |> String.mapi(fun i x -> if i=index then '-' else x)
s1 |> printfn "%A"
```

Print: "foo-bar"

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FjFR1

Comment: This is the prettiest solution, although it probably uses as much memory as the replaceAt solution.

Comment: My tests show it uses twice the memory and 5x the running time as my `replaceAt` function. It is "more functional" though, if that excites you.

Comment: @Daniel, Big difference. Can you show how you tested? I tried to run your code but did not work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMwJBq

Comment: I updated my answer with the test code and measurements.

Answer (score 2):

You could work with `char array` directly instead of wrapped with `StringBuilder`.

```
let replaceAt i c (s: string) = 
    let arr = s.ToCharArray()
    arr.[i] <- c
    String arr

"foo.bar" |> replaceAt 3 '-'
```

Some tests comparing it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30626440/162396) using `mapi`—

```
let replaceAt2 index x s = s |> String.mapi (fun i x -> if i=index then '-' else x)

let test f =
    let rec loop n =
        if n > 0 then
            let x = "foo.bar" |> f 3 '-'
            loop (n - 1)
    loop 10000000

test replaceAt  // Real: 00:00:01.188, CPU: 00:00:01.201, GC gen0: 168, gen1: 168, gen2: 0
test replaceAt2 // Real: 00:00:05.587, CPU: 00:00:05.584, GC gen0: 275, gen1: 275, gen2: 0
```

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? I just can't understand why the code is not working: dotnetfiddle.net/uMwJBq

Comment: You need to `open System` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

There are already good suggestions here. Here's another way to do it:

```
let s = "foo.bar"
let idx = s.LastIndexOf '.'
let replaced = s.Substring(0, idx) + "-" + s.Substring(idx + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it I tried a "more" functional approach with `List.foldBack`. Try the code below for yourself at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OKzIx6).

```
let replaceLastOf candidate replacement l = 
    let replaceAndPrepend x (xs, found) =
        if not found && x = candidate 
        then (replacement::xs, true)
        else (x::xs, found)
    fst <| List.foldBack replaceAndPrepend l ([], false)

let replaceLastCharOf candidate replacement (str:string) =
    List.ofSeq str
    |> replaceLastOf candidate replacement
    |> Array.ofList 
    |> System.String.Concat
```

**Usage**:

```
printfn "%A" (replaceLastOf 1 9 [1;3;1;4;1])
printfn "%A" (replaceLastCharOf '.' '-' "f.oo.bar")
```

**Output**:

```
[1; 3; 1; 4; 9]
"f.oo-bar"
```